Ошибка запуска приложения Setzer в Ubuntu 24.04 после обновления
После обновления с Ubuntu 22.04 до 24.04 приложение Setzer отказывается запускаться с следующими двумя ошибками:

Основная ошибка

** (setzer:39293): ERROR **: 10:54:32.733: Failed to fully launch dbus-proxy: Дочерний процесс завершился с кодом 1
Ловушка трассировки/останова (образ памяти сброшен на диск)


Связана с используемой темой и является, скорее, предупреждением - привожу лишь для полноты, на всякий пожарный:

(setzer:40436): Adwaita-WARNING **: 10:58:31.260: No known Yaru accent 'remix'
/usr/bin/setzer:133: DeprecationWarning: Gtk.Widget.show is deprecated
  self.main_window.show()
bwrap: setting up uid map: Permission denied

Что требуется исправить, если это вообще возможно?
